# Extracting the permalink from a post instance

Tags: posts, get-posts

I'm exporting some posts from a WordPress site.

One of the attributes of a post instance derived from `$posts = get_posts();` is guid .. `$post->guid` which shows how to find the original post. Something like `https://www.domain.com.au/?p=2152`

When I go to a browser and paste in the guid URL it often redirects to the permalink URL which is the URL I'd like to reference back to.

How do you extract the permalink from a post instance derived from `get_posts()`?

Comment: the pretty URL is also known as the permalink, you'll get a lot more/better results trying to search with permalink rather than pretty URL. Also, GUIDs aren't always URLs, or the current URL of the post, don't trust them blindly

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell. permalink searching was fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tom's suggestion of searching for permalink instead of pretty URLs I found the get_permalink function.

```
$permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
```